# How to color each li in css in different colors

Tags: html, css

every body
I have this css color every li it's work
You can see example in this article
https://devlopertechnology.blogspot.com/2019/11/software-engineering-software-project.html

This the code my question is in the end

```
.post ul li:nth-of-type(12){
  background-color: #9FA4C4;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(13) {
  background:   #B3CDD1 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(14) {
  background:   #9E768F ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(15) {
  background:   #9FA4C4 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(16) {
  background:   #B279A7 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(17) {
  background:   #D387AB ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(18) {
  background:   #864BA2 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(21) {
  background:   #BF3A30 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(10) {
  background:   #6E45E1 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(11) {
  background:   #89D4CF ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background:   #A7ACD9 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background:   #9E8FB2;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background:   #A88BEB ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(5) {
  background:   #F8CEEC ;
}

.post ul li:nth-of-type(6) {
  background:   #B58ECC ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(7) {
  background:   #5DE6DE ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(8) {
  background:   #647DEE ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(9) {
  background:   #7F53AC ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(19) {
  background:   #77EED8 ;
}
.post ul li:nth-of-type(20) {
  background:   #9EABE4 ;
}
```

But I want to convert it to dynamic, using loop or function
If there is idea, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    // Fetch the list of elements matching the selector
    const listElements = document.querySelectorAll('.post ul li');
    // Store the colors in an array
    const colors = [here you can store the colors you want]; // Assuming this has the same number of values as the list in your html, otherwise the below loop will fail if the values are less.
    // Map each color with the corresponding list element
    for(let index in listElements) {
        listElements[index].style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    }
```

Comment: const listElements =document.querySelectorAll('.post ul li');
    
    const colors = ["#535b2d", "#23a6d5", "#2d335b", "#23a6d5", "#e73c7e", "#ffff0000" ]; 
    
    for(let index in listElements) {
        listElements[index].style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    } // note I added about 20 colors not work even, the colors are more than the list items

Comment: Share your  full file where you have written this code. Are you adding this inside the script tag ?

Comment: I add this code in head tag without script tag , then i add script tag  <script type='text/javascript'>
    const listElements = document.querySelectorAll('.post ul li');
 
    const colors = [  "#9EABE4","#77EED8", "#7F53AC","  #647DEE","#5DE6DE","#B58ECC",  "#F8CEEC","#F8CEEC",
"#A88BEB","#9E8FB2","#A7ACD9","#89D4CF",
"#6E45E1","#BF3A30" ,"#864BA2", "#D387AB" ,
 "#B279A7","#9FA4C4","#9E768F","#B3CDD1",
 "#9FA4C4"]; 
 
    for(let index in listElements) {
        listElements[index].style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    }
    </script>  but not working

Comment: Problem here in this code {{for(let index in listElements) {
        listElements[index].style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    }}}   here the message TypeError at line NaN: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Comment: Can make example and send me the link    like this https://codepen.io/ahmedabuata/pen/jOMwgwy

Comment: https://codepen.io/shreyashbhatt1996/pen/gOwXRQv have a look at this you made some mistakes in the code which i have fixed.
1. Be careful of the css selector you are using